# How to do proxy and TLS in golang

Tags: go, proxy, tls1.2

I am trying to route my requests through a proxy and also sending cert.pem in TLS config. Below code is throwing this error - **proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake**. When I change the proxy URL from https to HTTP, the same code works. However proxy URL with https works in python. Below is my code so far

```
certs := x509.NewCertPool()
pemFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile("cert.pem")
if err != nil {
    return
}
certs.AppendCertsFromPEM(pemFile)
tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
    RootCAs: certs,
}

proxyUrl, err := url.Parse("https://someproxyurlhere.com:8080")
if err != nil {
    return
}

t := &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: tlsConfig,
    Proxy:           http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl),
}

client := http.Client{
    Transport: t,
}

reqBody := "some JSON body here"

buff, err := json.Marshal(reqBody)
if err != nil {
    return
}

req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "https://someurlhere.com", bytes.NewBuffer(buff))
if err != nil {
    return
}

res, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    // Error here - proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
    return
}
defer res.Body.Close()
```

Python code

```
import requests
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = 'https://someproxyurlhere.com:8080'
response = requests.post("https://someurlhere.com",
                           json={'key': 'value'},
                           verify='cert.pem')
print(str(response.content))
```

Comment: *"However proxy URL with https works in python."* - please provide the working Python code too to demonstrate what you mean with this. Also the output `openssl s_client -connect someproxyurlhere.com:8080` would be useful to prove that the proxy itself actually speaks HTTPS - the common case is that the proxy itself is accessed by HTTP even for HTTPS URLs (the proxy just tunnels the connection to the final server when doing  a CONNECT command, so this preserves end-to-end security). It would especially be strange if the same proxy and port is both accessible by HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich updated with python code

Comment: `os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = 'https://someproxyurlhere.com:8080'` - requests does not really care about the protocol (https vs http) given here. It will use only the IP and port with plain HTTP to connect to the proxy.

Answer (score 2):

> When I change the proxy URL from https to HTTP, the same code works.

This is because you are using a HTTP proxy which need to be accessed by HTTP and not HTTPS even for `https://..` URLs. This is how HTTPS proxying usually works. Note that while in theory a proxy could sniff if it gets a plain or a TLS connection in practice proxies (and servers) use different ports for HTTP and HTTPS - thus if it works on one port with HTTP it will very likely not work on the same port with HTTPS.

> proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake.

This is because the proxy answers with an plain HTTP error to the strange HTTP request (which is actually the start of the TLS handshake).

> However proxy URL with https works in python.

While it looks that it works it actually doesn't. Python requests will still use plain HTTP to the proxy even if `https://` was given as URL.

You can try to do a simple TLS connection to the proxy itself, for example with Python or with `openssl s_client`. It will very likely fail with some handshake error because the proxy isn't actually expecting TLS.