# TLS error with HTTPS calls via proxy in Go

Tags: go, https, proxy

I want to make https calls via a third party proxy using Go.

The third party proxy accepts a username and password.

My code works fine when I call the proxy using http. But I get a runtime error when I change the proxy to https.

The error message is:

proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x1248521]

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {

    // proxyURL - change to https get runtime error
    proxyStr := "http://username:password@ip:port"
    proxyURL, err := url.Parse(proxyStr)
    if err != nil { log.Println(err) }

    // targetURL
    targetStr := "https://httpbin.org/get" 
    targetURL, err := url.Parse(targetStr)
    if err != nil { log.Println(err) }

    //config Transport w Proxy
    transport := &http.Transport{
        Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyURL),
    }

    //config Client w Transport
    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: transport,
    }

    //config Request
    request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", targetURL.String(), nil)
    if err != nil { log.Println(err) }

    log.Println("Requesting", targetStr)

    //try it
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    if err != nil { log.Println(err) }

    log.Println(response.Status)
}
```

Comment: Do you just change the protocol of the proxy from `http://` to `https://` but keep IP and port? This will not work since the proxy will not expect HTTPS on the same port as it does HTTP. But maybe this is also a misunderstanding on how a HTTP proxy works: to proxy HTTPS the proxy can still be itself HTTP. The client will use the CONNECT request to build an end-to-end TLS tunnel through the proxy in this case, i.e. the connection will also be protected between client and proxy this way.

Comment: Yes you're right, I change the protocol only, keeping the IP and port the same. I'm not sure I follow your comment about the client using a CONNECT request. Are you recommending I change it from a GET to CONNECT? Thanks

Comment: CONNECT is done implicitly when using HTTPS over a HTTP proxy. The GET is then done inside the TLS tunnel which is created by the CONNECT. No need to change anything in your application. See [HTTP tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel) for more information.

Comment: thanks for clarifying and your help. (I don't have the ability to accept your answer.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do proxy and TLS in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61401128/how-to-do-proxy-and-tls-in-golang)

Comment: Yes it does thank you.